# how to grant all priviledges to all objects(tables, views, procedure, function etc) to a role in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

role created:

```
create role rl_new
```

want to give all priviledges to all objects like tables, views, procedures, function , etc to that role.

```
grant all on all_objects to rl_new
```

what is the right way to give all priviledges to all objects  to role?

Comment: Do you want to grant all privileges for specific schemas, or for the entire database? If you want to grant access to everything on the database, then you might want to look into system privileges, like `grant select any table to rl_new;`

Answer (score 2):

`all_objects` is a just a view so, no, that isn't what you want.  You'd need to grant access to each object individually.  You can use dynamic SQL to make that easier.  For example

```
begin
  for t in (select * from user_tables)
  loop
    execute immediate 'grant all on ' || t.table_name || ' to rl_new';
  end loop
end;
```

Of course, you'd need to do something similar for the different types of objects you want to give grants on.

Going forward, you'll need to include the grants in the scripts that you deploy to create new objects as well.

Comment: What about using All_objects view instead of user_tables?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - `all_objects` shows everything that you have access to.  In general, you wouldn't have the ability to grant access to those objects.  You'd also have to filter out things that you can't grant access on (i.e. private synonyms).  Plus you'd need to generate different grants for the different object types.  Given that, I'd rather just have separate sections that query from `user_tables`, `user_views`, etc.

Comment: or use`user_objects` in your cursor and apply a case statement on the `object_type` column to build the specific sql statement for each type of object.